# AngularJS search box in navbar loads table in view

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Hi I have a table of data that I need to filter.  I need to be able to filter the data with a navbar search box that is outside of the view where my table data will be displayed.  I'm not really sure how to do this.  I have this code inside my navbar this is where the search box should be:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchText" name="searchText" ng-model="query">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">                    
                <!--<a class="btn default-btn lookupbtn" ng-href="#/lookup">Lookup</a>-->
                <button class="btn default-btn lookupbtn">Lookup</button>
```

My table data currently looks like this:

```
<div>
<div>Lookup Results</div>
<!--<div><input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" ng-model="query" /></div>-->
<table ng-if="query">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Acc. ID</td>
            <td>Acc. Name</td>
            <td>Acc Address</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Zip</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Parent Name</td>
            <td>Account Type</td>
            <td>Account Status</td>
            <td>Credit Term</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results | filter:query ">
            <td>{{ result.accountId }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.state }}</td>
            <td>{{ reuslt.zip }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.parentName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountType }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.creditTerm }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get the navbar search box to work with the table in my view?  If any other info is needed please let me know.
 If a plnkr is needed just let me know and I'll make one.

Comment: have you tried adding an `ng-click` to your button and then a function in your controller to return the results?  So like `ng-click=fnSearch()` ?

Comment: @ewahner I'm not sure how to write the custom filter that I would need.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this would be to use `$rootScope`. When you add your `query` variable to $rootScope instead of your local $scope, it becomes available everywhere in your app, including your views.

Another option would be to use a service for that specific purpose. That service would be a singleton that stores the `query` value and allows you to set / get it when needed. It's more complex though usually considered a better practice than using `$rootScope`.

Comment: Can you show me a code example, or point me to an example?  I'm super new to Angular.

Comment: If you can create a Plunkr with your current code, I could fix it there

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/YSuDk14bOI9AcQxHpfft?p=catalogue  There's a plunkr for you.  The button that needs to be clicked for the search is the Lookup button.  I'm new to Plnkr too.  So uhhh if you need any more code just let me know.

Comment: Your code is working already. I'm not sure what there is to fix in your Plunkr.

Comment: what's not working is the lookup button in the navbar.  I need the user to be able to enter in a search item in the input on the navbar page and then have it displayed in a table on the lookup.html page.